# How do I delete a list column?

Tags: list-view, column, delete

In a SharePoint list, I have somehow ended up with duplicate columns of the "Title" column.  I only want to keep the original column title.

Besides hiding the columns, how do I remove these extra columns?  What might I have done to create these columns so that I don't accidentally do it again?

Below is a pic of the All items view from the List Settings. Full Name, Name, Name 2 are all the same column. If you don't hide them the same column will display three times.

You cannot select them and delete them.  The delete option does not exist for these three columns.

Thanks,

[image: All Items, From List Settings]

Answer (score 2):

The screen to manage columns is list settings, not the view. The view definition always has three version of the title field, as each has different options. One will display the field with a menu of options, one will have the field linked to the item, and the other will have just the text value, no link and no menu.

Though, it is odd that the title field is showing with two different names. I'd try going to the field settings from the list settings screen and seeing what's displayed there, and perhaps to try renaming it again there to see if that resets it.

From a modern list, to get to the list settings, go to the gear icon --> list settings

Comment: Mike, I showed the list view because not all the columns even show up in the list settings. thanks for taking the time to respond, I do appreciate it!  I'll keep trying to figure out where they came from and how to delete them.

Comment: A lot of the columns in the list are added by the system, and don't show up in the list settings, like the label, retention, item is a record, and others. If you don't use these, no worries, and no need to delete.